# Pasar lista de String a JSON Object

Tags: android, android-studio, json, array

Tengo una lista de JSON pero me retorna lo siguiente:

```
{"product":"[[\"5a10de2d8bb9d715c320acd8\",
 [\"5a08d4495d0e296cab3b5637\"]]"}
```

No es un JSON correcto.

Tengo una lista de String donde almaceno los valores y luego lo paso como parámetro al JSON.

Lo ideas es que la respuesta sea

```
 "product": [
                "5a08d4495d0e296cab3b5637"
            ]
```

La clases es la siguiente:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerListaProductos;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ProductosCarrito> listaProductos;
private List<Productos> productosLista;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
List<String> allProduct = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();

private TextView textProductoCarrito;
private TextView textPrecioCarrito;
private ImageView btnComprarCarrito;

Configuracion configuracion = new Configuracion();

String orderId, status, total, product, user, nameProduct, imagenProducto, tiempo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_productos_carrito);

    textProductoCarrito = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNombreProductoCarrito);
    textProductoCarrito = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPrecioCarrito);
    btnComprarCarrito = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCarrritoAll);


    recyclerListaProductos = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyProductosCarrito);
    recyclerListaProductos.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerListaProductos.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();

    adapter = new AdapterProductosCarrito(listaProductos, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerListaProductos.setAdapter(adapter);

    loadRecyclerViewData();


}

private void loadRecyclerViewData() {

    Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();


    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando carrito de compras...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            configuracion.rutacarrito()+"/"+datos.getString("user"),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

                        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            ProductosCarrito productos = new ProductosCarrito(
                                    o.optString("product"),
                                    o.optString("status"),
                                    o.optString("total"),
                                    o.optString("user")

                            );
                            listaProductos.add(productos);
                            allProduct.add(o.optString("product"));
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

public void comprarAllCarro(View v) throws JSONException {

    final Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        jsonObject.put("product", allProduct);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("ERROR", jsonObject.toString());

    orderId = "MQt6";
    status = "Pendiente";
    total = datos.getString("price");
    product = jsonObject.toString();
    user = "5a0bc3c98d37a15299268c13";
    tiempo = datos.getString("time");

        CarritoDeCompras.ComprarNetworkingCarrito n = new ComprarNetworkingCarrito();
        n.execute(configuracion.rutaOrder(), RegistroDeUsuario.Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Productos comprados exitosamente.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("ERROR", product);




    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Inicio.class);
    startActivity(intent);



}

public class ComprarNetworkingCarrito extends AsyncTask {

    public static final int NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER = 1;

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        getJson((String) params[0], (Integer) params[1]);
        return null;
    }


    void getJson(String url, int state) {
        //Do a HTTP POST, more secure than GET
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        boolean valid = false;

        switch (state) {

            case RegistroDeUsuario.Networking.NETWORK_STATE_REGISTER:
                //Building key value pairs to be accessed on web
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orderId", orderId));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total", total));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", product));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));

                valid = true;


                break;
            default:
                // Toast.makeText(c, "Unknown state", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (valid == true) {
            //Reads everything that comes from server
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
                request.setEntity(entity);

                //Send off to server
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                //Reads response and gets content
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                String line = "";
                String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                //Read back server output
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(c, "Error during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            decodeResultIntoJson(stringBuffer.toString());

        } else {

        }
    }

    private void decodeResultIntoJson(String response) {

        if (response.contains("error")) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                String error = jo.getString("error");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);

            String success = jo.getString("success");
            String message = jo.getString("message");
            // Toast.makeText(c, "Register successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta es **¿por qué no es correcto?**. El JSON en sí es válido, y puedes leer el valor que dices obteniendo el array que hay en la llave productos, apuntando al índice `[1]`  de ese array. Ahora bien, si la respuesta del servicio que envía el JSON así depende de ti y necesitas otro tipo de respuesta más adecuado, debes entonces modificar el código del servicio REST para que responda como tú esperas a la petición.

Comment: Sucede que el JSON que tengo lo quiero enviar como objeto de tipo JSON, es decir:
"product": [
                "5a08d4495d0e296cab3b5637", 
                "5a08d4495d0e296cab3b5638"
            ]

Pero cuando lo envío, hay unos corchetes y llaves que impiden que el formato que envío sea correcto. Cómo haría ene se caso?

Comment: Lo que tienes que modificar es el código en el servicio REST al cual consultas desde Android. No sé si has entendido bien el concepto. La respuesta viene así porque el servicio REST o API, como quieras llamarle, está programado para responder así. Por lo tanto, si el REST depende de ti deberás modificarlo para que responda como esperas. No sé a qué corresponde el JSON que pusiste más abajo, el cual por cierto debería estar en la pregunta, y no debajo... el espacio de abajo es para las respuestas de otros. Todo lo que sea aclaratorio con respecto a la pregunta debe ir en la misma pregunta.

Comment: El servicio me responde bien, lo que yo quiero es mandarle los valores de product que ves en el comentario de abajo. LO que yo quiero es llenar una lista de productos. Pero cuando mando el POST, ese arreglo se va con una estructura equivocada. Pienso que puede ser una concersión de String a JSON Object.

Comment: Entonces tienes que saber exactamente cómo te pide el servicio que le mandes los datos. Generalmente lo puedes hacer mediante una URL  o mediante una HashMap, pero eso depende de cómo esté programado el servicio. Si no indicas eso en la pregunta y muestras el código de cómo construyes la petición que envías al servicio será imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Como comentario puse el código donde armo la respuesta. El loadRecyclerViewData es donde obtengo los datos y con el POST envío, que es donde tengo la inconsistencia. 
Lo que quiero es pasar los valores a product, en el JSOn que compartir abajo.

Comment: A ver, tienes que [editar la misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/118594/edit)  agregando en ella las cosas que faltan. El espacio de abajo es para respuestas. Si por cada edición tú agregas una respuesta la cosa se va a complicar. Es importante que entiendas cómo funciona el sitio.